# Static variable to thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, declare

In the class program i declare a couple of integers. In the Mains method they get a value. These values are used in the telbereik method, but when the thread starts these values reset to 0. I want them to have the value that is given by the user in the Main method.

```
namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static int e, p,b,m,teller;
        //static long e;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] inputs = input.Split(' ');
            teller = 0;
            int p = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[4]);
            int e = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[2]);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[1]);
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[3]);
            Thread[] ts = new Thread[p];
            for (int t = 0; t < p; t++)
            {
                ts[t] = new Thread(telbereik);
            }
            for(int t=0;t<p;t++)
            {
                ts[t].Start(t);
            }
            /*for (int t = 0; t < p; t++)
            {
                ts[t].Join();
            }*/



        }
        public static void telbereik(object mt)
        {

            int threadnum=Convert.ToInt32(mt);

            int nepeind = e - b;
            int rest = nepeind % p;
            int eind = (nepeind / p) * p;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to code in 1 language. CountRange instead of telbrereik. This will keep your code more clean and concise. It will also help team members or people on stackoverflow to read your code.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I write it for a school project, but next time when i post something, I will translate it.

Comment: Don't translate it. ALWAYS code in 1 language. All code examples are in English, if you ever grab an example from the internet, you will not convert it to Dutch either. The keywords of the programming language are English, therefore the code itself should be English.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will keep that in mind. Sometimes i get format codes for my study, I have to modify them, they can be in Dutch. But still it doesn't take a lot of time to make them English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you not redefining the variables in Main method?
instead of int p = ? , just p = ?. should work

Comment: Yep that was it. Thx!!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your questions, please mark it as accepted.